# mydomain.com/anything on AWS S3

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am hosting my website on AWS S3. The only file I have there is `example.com/index.html`.

Is it possible to let users land on `example.com/anything` (where `anything` stands for any valid URI) so that while the user still sees `example.com/anything` in the address bar the `example.com/index.html?param=anything` is invoked instead?

If this is not possible on S3, what technology would allow me to do this?

What is the name of want I want to do? Masking? Redirecting?

EDIT: I don't really need the `anything` URI as a parameter as long as I can determined from within `index.html` via JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. This is an extremely common use of mod_rewrite in Apache, or routes in other web servers like nginx. You should search Google for URL rewriting, then come back here if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell, just knowing the name of what I want to do helped me a lot.

Comment: @EdCottrell, the question is about static hosting on S3.  Not Apache or nginx.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Oops. You are absolutely right; for some reason, I read this as being about AWS, period, and assumed OP was using EC2 as well.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek See my discussion with Michael above. You will need a real server (such as Apache on an EC2 instance) in front of your S3 files.

Comment: Thanks - and can you please tell me more? So I will have EC2 with Apache, I will use mod_rewrite to ... and pass the *anything* to ... ? After the rewrite, can I still serve my index.html?param=anything from S3 so that I utilize the price and scale of S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with just S3, instead you need to run EC2 micro instance with URL rewrite script.